# Multiselect values and keep order of original list in result when reselecting

Tags: excel, vba

I use this macro for a multiselect of values in a cell dropdown option list:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzjhtEHCRmY

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JU7G_Tna2zPBtcG2TlarxKCTbuinNsg5LwBqzmuJYK8/edit

Macro:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim strVal As String
Dim i As Long
Dim lCount As Long
Dim Ar As Variant
On Error Resume Next
Dim lType As Long
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

lType = Target.Validation.Type
If lType = 3 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    newVal = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    oldval = Target.Value
    Target.Value = newVal
    If Target.Column = 3 Then
        If oldVal = "" Then
        Else
            If newVal = "" Then   
            Else
                On Error Resume Next
                Ar = Split(oldVal, ", ")
                strVal = ""
                For i = LBound(Ar) To UBound(Ar)
                    Debug.Print strVal
                    Debug.Print CStr(Ar(i))
                    If newVal = CStr(Ar(i)) Then
                        strVal = strVal
                        lCount = 1
                    Else
                        strVal = strVal & CStr(Ar(i)) & ", "
                    End If
                Next i
                If lCount > 0 Then
                    Target.Value = Left(strVal, Len(strVal) - 2)
                Else
                    Target.Value = strVal & newVal
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Yet, when reselecting a value which is in the dropdown list above another selected value, the re-selected value gets attached behind the other value. For example:

The dropdown list is:

```
Apple
Banana
Strawberry
```

When I select:

```
1. Apple, 2. Banana and 3. Strawberry
```

I get as result:

```
Apple, Banana, Strawberry
```

If I then 'unselect' Banana, I get ...

```
Apple, Strawberry
```

... and if I then 're-select' Banana, I get ...

```
Apple, Strawberry, Banana
```

BUT ... I would like to have ...

```
Apple, Banana, Strawberry
```

... so the order of the original list should apply.

How do I need to adjust the macro to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following procedure

```
Public Sub AddReordered(ByRef Target As Range, ByVal NewValue As String)
    Dim Output As String

    If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
        Dim TestString As String
        TestString = ", " & NewValue & ", "

        Dim Item As Variant
        For Each Item In Range(Target.Validation.Formula1).Value
            If InStr(1, TestString, ", " & Item & ", ") > 0 Then
                Output = IIf(Output <> vbNullString, Output & ", ", "") & Item
            End If
        Next Item
    End If

    Target.Value = Output
End Sub
```

And replace in your code

```
Target.Value = strVal & newVal
```

with

```
AddReordered Target, strVal & newVal
```

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: This will always use the same order for the cell as in the ComboBox.</sup>*

Comment: Thanks for the support. Could you show your whole script? For some reason I can then only do a single select if  I add the code and replace the suggested line ...

Comment: @PhilippM That is all, just used the script of your question and replaced the one line. What is the validation formula/range you used? Note your script only works for `Target.Column = 3` means it only works in column C.

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong. My old script still works ... I inserted you code under Option Explicit and then replaced the one liner ... but now I can only do single select ...

Comment: @PhilippM That's strange becaus as you can see it worked for me. You didn't answer my questions yet btw.